# Using jest and enzyme to test a click

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm new to unit tests and trying to build a test case for a click.  At the moment, I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: props.callModal is not a function
```

My test is coded out as the following:

```
it('Click a save for later button', () => {
  const mockCallBack = jest.fn();
  const saveBtn = shallow(<AskQuestion />);
  saveBtn.find('.save-for-later__button').simulate('click');
  expect(mockCallBack.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);
});
```

In VSCode, I'm seeing the error as:
[image]

What do I need to do in order to properly simulate the click?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was simpler than I realized.  After writing this out, it gave me an idea.  All I needed to do was add:

```
const callModal = jest.fn();
const saveBtn = shallow(<AskQuestion callModal={callModal});
```